# XMLHttpRequest not sending after upgrade to core 7

Tags: asp.net-core, xmlhttprequest, asp.net-core-7.0

I am updating a .NET 4.8 application to a Core 7 application, and am having an issue with the XMLHttpRequest sending `null` to the server.

```js
var url = 'ExportToExcel';
var fileName = filenameString + '.xlsx';
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
var params = '{"SentData": \'' + JSON.stringify(dataPacket) + '\'}';
req.open('POST', url, true);
req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');

req.responseType = 'blob';
req.onreadystatechange = function () {

  if (req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200) {
    //Convert the Byte Data to BLOB object.
    var blob = new Blob([req.response], { type: 'application/octetstream' });

    //Check the Browser type and download the File.
    var isIE = false || !!document.documentMode;
    if (isIE) {
      window.navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, fileName);
    } else {
      var url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      link = url.createObjectURL(blob);
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.setAttribute('download', fileName);
      a.setAttribute('href', link);
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();
      document.body.removeChild(a);
    }
  }
};

req.send(params);
```

```csharp
public ActionResult ExportToExcel(string SentData) // SentData is null
{
```

The server receives the request, but the data is null.

What changed when upgrading to Core?

Comment: You might need to make a model class that contains the string property and accept that as the parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The server receives the request, but the data is null. What changed
> when upgrading to Core?

The [xhttp.send()'s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) parameter is the request's body, not request's parameter. So if the backend need parameters, the script does not send any parameters.

So you have two choices here, either send your http parameter as [request body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#frombody-attribute) or as query string.

For sending as query string you can modify as following:

```cs
function httpPost(){

            var dataPacket = [];
            for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
                var items = {
                    CustomerCode: "CustomerCode:" + i,
                    RegNo: "RegNo:" + i,
                    FleetNo: "FleetNo:" + i,

                }
                dataPacket.push(items); // Creating Demo Data 

            }

            var params = JSON.stringify(dataPacket);
            console.log("param",params)
            var url = 'http://localhost:5094/Home/ExportToExcel?SentData=' + params + ''; // Passing parameter as query string

            console.log("url", url)


            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('POST', url, true);
            req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
            req.send();
        }


        var response = httpPost();
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please [refer to this official documnet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) for more detials. And for [asp.net core FromBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0#frombody-attribute)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I ended up using `FormData` and appended it. `var formData = new FormData(); formData.append('SentData', JSON.stringify(dataPacket); ... req.send(formData);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, yeah, that also resolve the null data in  parameter. Glad to know your issue has been resolved.